# Multi Record Validation in Oracle Forms

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracleforms

[Form Field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAdNo.png)

I wanted to apply validation on Plan Ratio field if user entered ratio exceed  100 then show error how can I  do in when validate trigger as plan ratio is the same field but have different records

Answer (score 1):

You can setup an invisible Calculated Item, that sums up Plan ratio field, name it for instance as SUMMARY_FIELD and then add WHEN-VALIDATE-ITEM trigger for each Plan ratio item of the records like this:

```
BEGIN
    IF :SUMMARY_FIELD>100 THEN
        message('nok'); --or whatever alert you like
        RAISE Form_Trigger_Failure;
    END IF;
END;
```

PS. How to create Calculated Item:

> To create a calculated item:
>
> ```
> 1. In the Object Navigator, create a new interface item (make sure it is a control item). 
>
>
>
>   Tip: The item's datatype must be compatible with the calculation you wish to use to 
>
>    compute the item's value. For example, if you wish to compute an item's value with the 
>
>    Sum function, create an interface item of datatype Number. 
>
>
>
> 2. Double-click the item's object icon to display the Property Palette. 
>
> 3. Under the Calculation node, set the item's Calculation Mode property to Formula or 
>
>    Summary. 
>
> 4. If you set Calculation Mode to: 
>
>
>
>    Formula, click on the Formula property, click the More button to display the Formula 
>
>    dialog, and type a PL/SQL expression to define the formula. Click OK to compile the 
>
>    expression.  
>
>
>
>    Summary, use the Summary Function popList to select a summary type, then use the 
>
>    Summarized Block and Summarized Item popLists to select the block and item whose 
>
>   values will be summarized to compute a value for the calculated item.
> ```

Comment: Thanks bro for your help